# Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```
 db.Open();

 string updateString = "SELECT TOP 1 RTRIM(kol) kol, RTRIM(adres) adres, RTRIM(numwave) numwave FROM sorters WHERE kodprod=@kodprod AND sorter_kod=@sorter AND moved_ok IS NULL ORDER BY CAST(kol as int)";
 try
 {
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateString, db);
     //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numdoc", NumDoc);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kodprod", KodProd.Id);
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sorter", SorterKod);
     SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
     reader.Read();//here error
     Kol = reader["kol"].ToString();
     Adres = reader["adres"].ToString();
     NumWave = reader["numwave"].ToString();
     NumDoc = reader["numdoc"].ToString();
     reader.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  { }
```

Why do I get this error when I run my code?:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Comment: Are you getting error at compile time or runtime?

Comment: Not related with the error, but it looks like you misspelled the word Address. You may get an error if it is correctly spelled on the database. If not in the future may cause confusion.

Comment: @Roman whats your next problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should do a `while loop` to check reader contain data. You can also use `IF` if you are sure the query return only one row. If more than one row you should use `While`. In your case `IF` also do the job because you are only taking `TOP1`

```
string updateString = "SELECT TOP 1 RTRIM(kol) kol, RTRIM(adres) adres,
                       RTRIM(numwave) numwave FROM sorters WHERE 
                       kodprod=@kodprod AND sorter_kod=@sorter
                      AND moved_ok IS NULL ORDER BY CAST(kol as int)";
                try
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateString, db);
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numdoc", NumDoc);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kodprod", KodProd.Id);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sorter", SorterKod);
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while(reader.Read())
                     {
                    Kol = reader["kol"].ToString();
                    Adres = reader["adres"].ToString();
                    NumWave = reader["numwave"].ToString();
                    NumDoc = reader["numdoc"].ToString();
                     } 
                    reader.Close();
                }
```

Comment: here my next problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473331/invalid-attempt-to-read-when-no-data-is-present#comment49027342_30473390)

Comment: @Roman can you show the code where you assing value for kodProd.Id and SorterKod

Comment: I'm sorry. You mean this one? [link](http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/05/f14f3b7c00fc97561e05f141e828084e.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

You can check whether the DataReader is ready to fetch the rows

```
if(reader.HasRows)
{
   //do the coding here
}
```

Comment: Okay, that problem solved) Tnx.
But now i got a next problem.

Comment: My Query don't work correctly. 
Here my table columns :
[link](http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/05/24853a7a8aa89bb9d99f04432a5ba28e.png)
Here query in SQL:
[link](http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/05/a003be01635a074900c5f5aa6dd801f1.png)

In c# its return 0 Rows

Comment: In the SQL link you have given the query with out any Order By, but in the code you have given in your question, Order By is used.  Tell me onething why you have used Order By for Top 1 row filter.  Its meaning less

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error will in fact occur on the next line, viz when you access the reader via the index `[]` operator. What you need to do is check the result of `reader.Read()` before accessing it:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
    Kol = reader["kol"].ToString();
    Adres = reader["adres"].ToString();
    NumWave = reader["numwave"].ToString();
    NumDoc = reader["numdoc"].ToString();
}
```

Since you are only returning a maximum of one row (`TOP 1`) there will either be zero or one rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reader.HasRows`

```
string updateString = "SELECT TOP 1 RTRIM(kol) kol, RTRIM(adres) adres, RTRIM(numwave) numwave FROM sorters WHERE kodprod=@kodprod AND sorter_kod=@sorter AND moved_ok IS NULL ORDER BY CAST(kol as int)"; 
try 
{ 
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(updateString, db); 
//command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numdoc", NumDoc); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kodprod", KodProd.Id); 
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sorter", SorterKod); SqlDataReader 
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if(reader.HasRows)
 while(reader.Read())//here error 
{ 
Kol = reader["kol"].ToString(); 
Adres = reader["adres"].ToString(); 
NumWave = reader["numwave"].ToString(); 
NumDoc = reader["numdoc"].ToString(); 
} 
reader.Close(); 
}
catch{}
```

EDIT: sorry for the bad formatting, posting code from the Android app is a mess.

EDIT: See Microsoft example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)